# How to get name of street or address via Longitude and Latitude on window phone sdk

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

C# - Please tell me how to get name of street or address if we know Longitude and Latitude.

Answer (score 2):

Using ReverseGeoCoding, which is available as a part of the sdk in windows phone os version 8

Reverse Geo Coding takes the latitude and longitude and returns the string address or location of those points in the globe.

check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthiasshapiro/archive/2013/06/14/reverse-geocoding-in-windows-phone-8.aspx) link

and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jrspinella/archive/2012/11/02/using-reversegeocodequery-for-windows-phone-8.aspx) also

**Raw usage**

```
ReverseGeocodeQuery reverseGeocode = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
reverseGeocode.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(gCordinate.Latitude, gCordinate.Longitude);
reverseGeocode.QueryCompleted += reverseGeocode_QueryCompleted;
reverseGeocode.QueryAsync();

void reverseGeocode_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            txtCompleteAddress.Text = "operation was cancelled";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            txtCompleteAddress.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
        }
        else if (e.Result != null)
        {
            if (e.Result.Count > 0)
            {
                MapAddress geoAddress = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
                addressString1 = geoAddress.HouseNumber + " " + geoAddress.Street;
                addressString2 = geoAddress.District + ", " + geoAddress.City;
                addressString3 = geoAddress.Country;
                if (addressString1 != " ")
                    addressString1 = addressString1 + "\n";
                else
                    addressString1 = "";

                if (addressString2 != ",  ")
                    addressString2 = addressString2 + "\n";
                else
                    addressString2 = "";

                txtCompleteAddress.Text = addressString1 + addressString2 + addressString3;
            }
            else
            {
                txtCompleteAddress.Text = "no address found at that location";
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Some error occured in converting location geo Coordinates to location address, please try again later");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have the smallest clue how helpfull was this to me!